# How to get number without decimal places?

Tags: python, decimal

```
tunnid = int(input("Sisestage oma töötundide arv ühes nädalas: "))
tasu = int(input("Sisestage oma tunnitasu: "))

if tunnid <= 40:

    print("Teie nädalapalk on " + str(tunnid*tasu))

else:

    print("Teie nädalapalk on " + str(tunnid*tasu*1.5))
```

If i multiply 60*10 as else i should get 900, but program gives me 900.0
So my quiestion is, how to remove this .0 from the answer, what do i have to change in my code?

p.s Im just a beginner so don't judge please :)

Comment: That shouldn't even run; you can't add a string and an integer.  Don't you get a TypeError?

Comment: No it runs normally, i use thing called Thonny btw

Comment: An operation between an `int` and a `float` returns a `float`, whether or not the result *could* be represented as an `int` exactly. Is there a reason you care? You could multiply by 3 then divide by (integer) 2 (or just pass the resulting float to `int` to drop the non-integer part) and live with the resulting loss of precision if the product is odd.

Answer (score 16):

Just convert the number with `int`:

```
print('Teie nädalapalk on {}'.format(int(tunnid * tasu * 1.5)))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `format` mini-language:

```
print('Teie nädalapalk on {:.0f}'.format(tunnid * tasu * 1.5))
```

The `.0f` tells the number to be truncated to 0 decimals (i.e. integer representation)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way will be to type-cast the `float` value to `int`. For example:

```
>>> x = 100.0
>>> x = int(x)
>>> x
100
```

Hence, in your code you should do:

```
print("Teie nädalapalk on " + str(int(tunnid*tasu)))
# Note: "str(tunnid*tasu)" replaced with "str(int(tunnid*tasu))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a typecast operation to convert float to int. Instead of `str(tunnid*tasu*1.5)` use `str(int(tunnid*tasu*1.5))`.
But this will strip the decimal part even when the product is not an integer.
If you want to handle that case as well you will have to add an additional check.

`if tunnid*tasu*1.5 - int(tunnid*tasu*1.5) > 1e-10: 
  print("Teie nädalapalk on " + str(tunnid*tasu*1.5)) 
 else 
  print("Teie nädalapalk on " + str(int(tunnid*tasu*1.5)))`

1e-10 is a very small number just to check if decimal part is non zero. You could decrease it further.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to make your answer an integer if i am correct you can do it by
typecasting it to integer as:

```
print("Teie nädalapalk on " + str(int(tunnid*tasu*1.5)))
```

it should give exactly what you want.
for more information to typecast float to int or vice versa you can refer here [Peterbe.com](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/interesting-casting-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> num = 900.0  # tunnid * tasu * 1.5
>>> int(num) if num == int(num) else num
900
>>> num = 900.6  # tunnid * tasu * 1.5
>>> int(num) if num == int(num) else num
900.6
```